# CP2102 device is not listed in /dev on macOS 13.5 M1 Chip

Tags: arduino, esp32

I currently have a WROOM ESP32 Board with a silicon Labs CP2012 controller. I installed the driver from the official website. (https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads). I cant seem to find the driver downloaded anywhere in the /dev/ folder nor do i get the UART TO USB port to connect my esp32 to my arduino ide. When i downloaded the driver, i pressed allow in the security and privacy setting when it prompted it to me

I tried ls /dev/* and this came up. /dev/tty

terminal check`
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port    /dev/ttysf
/dev/tty.wlan-debug         /dev/ttyt0